One bay of RaidSonic Icy Box suddenly stopped working, other 3 remain functional, how to diagnose root cause?
I have a RaidSonic Icy Box IB-3740-C31, USB-C 3.1. It's served me well for the last few years and paired with an N100 16GB mini pc it acts as my personal home server and NAS storage. Suddenly, one disk stopped working. I was suprised because it was a brand new disk, 2 months old. Swapping 2 disks, and using dmesg --follow I realised it's the bay, not the disk.
I took the disk from the faulty bay and plugged it into a spare USB-C sata adapter I had still around to recover my mergerfs and snapraid cluster.
All works as expected now but before buying a full replacement (~180$) I was wondering what may be the cause of a single bay to fail vs. the entire 4 bay system. And if it's something I can try to repair myself (I enjoy these things + it's less wasteful). But I wouldn't know where to start. Software based diagnostics would be ideal, soldering will be harder to do but I could use it as an opportunity to learn something new.
